# Random function is not importing properly in Python

Tags: python-2.7, importerror

I made a simple rock paper scissors game, and worked great, but now it is coming up with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RPS.py", line 1, in <module>
    from random import random
  File "/Users/gunnarvonhaden/Desktop/random.py", line 47, in <module>
    print rock()
  File "/Users/gunnarvonhaden/Desktop/random.py", line 6, in rock
    a = random()
NameError: global name 'random' is not defined
logout
```

This is the exact same code as I was using before, but now it is saying that there is no random function. This is my code for the program:

```
from random import *
def rock():
     print " "
     print "-----------------------------------------------"
     print " "
     a = random()
     if a <= 0.33:
         computerChoice = "rock"
     elif a <= 0.66 and a > 0.33:
         computerChoice = "paper"
     elif a > 0.66:
         computerChoice = "scissors"
     userChoice = raw_input("Rock, paper, or scissors: ").lower()
     if userChoice == "rock":
         if computerChoice == "rock":
             print "It's a tie"
             return rock()
         elif computerChoice == "scissors":
             print "You win!"
             return rock()
         elif computerChoice == "paper":
             print "You lose :("
             return rock()
     elif userChoice == "paper":
         if computerChoice == "rock":
             print "You win!"
             return rock()
         elif computerChoice == "paper":
             print "It's a tie"
             return rock()
         elif computerChoice == "scissors":
             print "You lose :("
             return rock()
     elif userChoice == "scissors":
         if computerChoice == "rock":
             print "You lose :("
             return rock()
         elif computerChoice == "paper":
             print "You win~"
             return rock()
         elif computerChoice == "scissors":
             print "It's a tie"
             return rock()
     else:
         print "I don't understand"
         return rock()
 print rock()
```

Why is this not working?  Am I going insane? Any input helps,
thanks.

Comment: Do you have a file called random.py in your project? Perhaps that is competing with the import.

Answer (score 0):

Name of your file can't be random.py. Rename it and try again.